# How can I test correctness of a program by removing or replacing lines of code?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mutation-testing

I know this question is very vague but I think with your help we can improve it. A couple of month ago in an interview talking about TDD and unit testing, I was asked if I knew I particular methodology (unfortunately I forgot the name) where a class or component gets probed for its correctness by removing or altering some lines (automatically, probably using a specific tool). 
As you can imagine I didn't get the job and I can't ask the question directly to them but it seems an interesting topic and it also seems they are using it. 
Anybody has heard about it?

Comment: What language? PIT is for Java but there are mutation testing tools for other languages too.

Comment: None in particular, just wondering the name of the technique and Google couldn't help..

Comment: I see. For the record, a good one for PHP is [Humbug](https://github.com/padraic/humbug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called Mutation Testing.

You could take a look at pitest 'Real world mutation testing'

http://pitest.org/

Comment: Thank you! mutation testing is exactly what I was after